# GLSL fragment shader garbage value

Tags: glsl, shader

I have a simple program that just loads a shader and draws a triangle strip.

When I use the following fragment shader

```
precision mediump float; 

varying vec2 v_Position;

uniform float u_Intensity;
uniform vec2 u_Range;
uniform vec2 u_Touch;

void main()
{    
    gl_FragColor = vec4 (v_Position.x / 300.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    return;
}
```

I get a nice gradient in the strip (v_Position is set to be the position that I'm passing in in the vertex shader).

When I use the following fragment shader

```
precision mediump float; 

varying vec2 v_Position;

uniform float u_Intensity;
uniform vec2 u_Range;
uniform vec2 u_Touch;

void main()
{    
    gl_FragColor = vec4 (u_Range.x / 300.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    return;
}
```

I get a solid color strip (u_Range.x is a constant at this point)

However, when I try to combine the two things:

```
precision mediump float; 

varying vec2 v_Position;

uniform float u_Intensity;
uniform vec2 u_Range;
uniform vec2 u_Touch;

void main()
{    

    if (v_Position.x < u_Range.x)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                                                                                  
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4 (u_Range.x / 300.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        return;
    }
}
```

I get garbage... It's like a strip with green and black noise.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something (I've been staring at this code for some time now)... I don't quite understand how or why adding a conditional, and setting gl_FragColor in both branches (if and else), gets me garbage.

Comment: You might just try a different driver.  I've seen GLSL conditionals get screwed up by driver bugs.

Comment: Check the InfoLog after the glCompileShader and glLinkProgram calls to see if there are any problems.  Tell us what GPU and driver you are using as that may be relevant.

Comment: The log is clean (I don't get any warnings), and I'm trying to run this on an iPhone 4. The problem seems to be happening _most_ of the time. That is to say, it worked once, but I'm not sure what I changed :\

Comment: The NVidia Cg compiler can provide an approximation of the ARB_fragment_program opcodes of the compiled shader. Have a look: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/395817-how-to-get-glsl-assembly/page__view__findpost__p__3622768

Comment: The "return" statements are unecessary.  A longshot, but those statements might be confusing the compiler since they're in a conditional.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the intermediate value to a temp variable in the conditional and assigning gl_fragColor outside of the conditional?